# URI Replace using TCL

Tags: tcl

I'm pretty new to TCL world and i was trying to replace the URI using the below script. but some how it works for initial request but not for the subsequent requests.

```
when HTTP_REQUEST {
  set http_uri [HTTP::uri]
  set http_host [string tolower [HTTP::header "Host"]]

  if { [HTTP::uri] matches_glob "/profile" } {
    HTTP::uri [string map {"/profile" "/account"} [HTTP::uri]]
  }
}
```

Comment: What Tcl extensions are you using that provide the `when` command and the `matches_glob` operator?

Comment: A `matches_glob` operator would require surgery to Tcl in the expression compiler at least because adding operators is currently really messy. (We ought to have something like it, but we don't.) Unless it's a non-standard `if` of course. By contrast, `when` is non-standard, but a reasonable thing that people could do with a bit of scripting.

Answer (score 0):

I'd expect the code to look more like this:

```
when HTTP_REQUEST {
    set http_uri [HTTP::uri]
    set http_host [string tolower [HTTP::header "Host"]]

    if {[string match "/profile" $http_uri]} {
        HTTP::uri [string map {"/profile" "/account"} $http_uri]
    }
}
```

Except that it's probably not the whole URI that you want to match, but rather just the prefix of the path part. (I don't know the package that you're using that provides the `when` command, so what I just wrote might seem odd.) Because of concerns like that, using a regular expression to do the rewrite is probably a better plan; they're much more sophisticated, but correspondingly trickier to write:

```
when HTTP_REQUEST {
    set http_uri [HTTP::uri]
    set http_host [string tolower [HTTP::header "Host"]]

    # If we successfully rewrite a _whole_ leading path component...
    if {[regsub {^/profile\M} $http_uri /account http_uri]} {
        # ...write the rewritten path back
        HTTP::uri $http_uri
    }
}
```

The `\M` in the RE means match end-of-word. Perfect for this case!

Comment: The result of `regsub` with a target variable is the number of substitutions performed. Very useful for this pattern.